# WPF .Net Core 3.1 Dependency Injection/Service Reference Question

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to reference a method in a_UserTenant from my Domain class

This is the top section:

```
public IServiceProvider Services { get; set; }
private readonly A_UserTenant a_UserTenant;
private readonly A_User a_User;
private string Username = null;

public Domain(string Username)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Username = Username;
    UsernameTextbox.Text = Username;
    loading = new Loading.Loading();
    this.a_UserTenant = this.Services.GetRequiredService<A_UserTenant>();
    this.a_User = this.Services.GetRequiredService<A_User>();
}
```

This is my App.Xaml

```
public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

public IConfiguration configuration { get; private set; }

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

    configuration = builder.Build();

    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

    ServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    var login = ServiceProvider.GetService<Login>();
    login.Show();
}

private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton(configuration);
    LoadSDR_ManageWSControllers loadSDR_ManageWSControllers = new LoadSDR_ManageWSControllers();
    loadSDR_ManageWSControllers.Services(services);

    //Views
    services.AddTransient(typeof(Login));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(Domain));

}
```

The issue now is that I get an Exception saying -

> $exception    {"Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'provider')"} System.ArgumentNullException

This is the constructor of the A_UserTenant class:

```
private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

public A_UserTenant(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this.configuration = configuration;
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

EDIT:

This is one of the methods in A_UserTenant that I want to call from my Domain class

```
public UserTenant Get(string Id)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    var link = $"{link]}Directory/UserTenant/Get";
    var username = uname;
    var password = upw;
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri(link);
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    request.AddParameter("Id", Id);
    request.Method = Method.GET;
    var res = client.Execute(request);
    if (res.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserTenant>(res.Content);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is how I navigate to the Domain class from another class currently:

```
Domain domain = new Domain(Username);
domain.Show();
this.Close();
```

Comment: you want to use asp.net core DI in wpf?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you aren't using `IOptions<T>` for strong configuration types?

Comment: "Parameter 'provider'" I'm not seeing a provider parameter, what's the full stack trace?

Comment: By the looks of it, you have an instance member `IServiceProvider Services` and you are expecting it to be automagically allocated for you in your view, which said bluntly is not going to work out well for you, it is going to be null

Comment: @LeiYang Yes, I read that it was possible?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I'm sorry, I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: @TheGeneral May I know how to do DI correctly in this instance?

Comment: @JianYA i suggest you use som DI framework such as [Autofac](https://autofac.org/), instead of copy some code from asp.net core.

Comment: This all comes down to, what are these dependencies you are requesting `A_User` etc, where do they come from, and why you are expecting them to be in the service provider

Comment: @TheGeneral I edited my question to show what i am trying to call in A_UserTenant.

Comment: You are hitting an exception, but you've left out important details about it. Like the stack trace. That's said, I'm guessing the exception is being thrown by the `.GetRequiredService<T>()` extension method, because `this.Services == null`.

Comment: this.a_UserTenant = this.Services.GetRequiredService<A_UserTenant>(); is the line pointed out by the stacktrace. How do I load the services?

Comment: I think the question is how do I navigate to the Domain class from another class and reference A_UserTenant? If I put A_UserTenant in the constructor, it will request for it as a parameter next to username.

Comment: You registered `Domain` as a transient service, but your constructor `Domain(string Username)` implies that you aren't creating `Domain` from your service provider. You'll need to inject either the service provider, or the actual services you want, somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, you're registering `Domain` as a service;

```cs
services.AddTransient(typeof(Domain));
```

But your constructor implies that the caller is calling `new` directly, rather than obtaining the instance from the service provider;

```cs
public Domain(string Username) {...}

// maybe the caller looks like this?
var domain = new Domain(username);
```

Getting the design right will be little tricky.

You want each service constructor to explicitly list the actual required services, so you don't fall into the "service locator" anti-pattern.

But you don't want every caller to know anything about those dependencies.

You have a couple of choices to mix service dependencies and parameters. You could move assigning the parameters to an instance method. Then perhaps encapsulate everything in a static method;

```cs
public class Domain{
    private Domain(A_UserTenant a_UserTenant, A_User a_user) {...}
    private void SetUsername(string Username) {...}

    public static Domain Factory(IServiceProvider provider, string Username) 
    {
        var domain = services.GetRequiredServce<Domain>();
        domain.SetUsername(username);
        return domain;
    }
}

var domain = Domain.Factory(services, username);
```

Or you could leave the form out of the service collection and instead only register the dependencies in a new service class;

```cs
public Domain(string Username, DomainDependencies dependencies) {...}

var domain = new Domain(
    username,
    services.GetRequiredService<DomainDependencies>()
);
```

Either way, you'd need to pass around at least the `IServiceProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. for the instance method, How do I then navigate into the Domain class from another class? You are correct in that I call new directly from another class. But with the parameters there, does that mean I have to inject all my intended services into the first startup class then pass it around?

Comment: var domain = services.GetRequiredServce<Domain>();
domain.SetUsername(username);
Where do I put this? Do i put it inside the Domain class also?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use as thing as .Net Core Dependency Injection in WPF, for this you may use reflections. For example for getting running services types by its interface:

```
var interfaceType = typeof(IServiceProvider );
var services = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(w => interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(w)).ToList();
```

and after this you can create instances by using `Activator.CreateInstance(<your service>) as <Service class>;`

Comment: the answer has nothing to do with dependency injection.

Comment: It is not dependency injection, but similar to it, in WPF i called my services like this, what else you recommend for this case?

Comment: DI also uses REFLECTIONS in back side

Comment: the OP is asking about using asp.net core DI in wpf, not manually make a DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency injection system needs to have *all* the information necessary to construct a service defined ahead of time in the ConfigureService method. That isn't possible in this case since you Domain class requires a string to be constructed. You could create some sort of IDomainService that has a CreateDomain(string name) method and inject that.